# Unable to interact with the application via minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm learning kubernetes via a LinkedIn learning course. A tutorial I'm doing runs this [hello world application](https://github.com/karthequian/docker-helloworld) via `kubectl` and `minikube`. Everything appears in working order, but I cannot interact with the application using `minikube service helloworld`. The request keeps timing out.

The tutorial first asks to create a deployment using the command `kubectl create -f helloworld.yaml` then to expose the service via command `kubectl expose deployment helloworld --type=NodePort` and then it says interact with the app by doing `minikube service helloworld`. The diagnostics after create and expose show that everything on my end matches the tutorial's setup, but the last step fails for me whereas it launches the browser and shows the hello world app in the tutorial demo.

How would I go about debugging this error as an absolute beginner?

EDIT:

When I run `kubectl describe services`, I get the following output

```
$ kubectl describe services
Name:                     helloworld
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=helloworld
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.96.6.203
IPs:                      10.96.6.203
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30433/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.2:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

When I check the port 30433, by doing `nc -zv <hostname> 30433`, I get an error:

```
nc: connectx to <hostname> port 30433 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connectx to <hostname> port 30433 (tcp) failed: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: i searched but found `minikube service` is to expose service url.but in the github repo i don't find anywhere that require you run `minikube service`. so try access `http://localhost:TheNodePort` in browser directly.

Comment: @LeiYang: My experiments show that ```minikube service <service name> --url``` is to get the service URL. But, if you omit ```--url```, it opens your web browser and connects to the port that the service is listening.

Comment: have you solved your timeout issue?

Comment: @LeiYang: No. There is something strange with the service, while kubectl shows the service as running, when I run a netcat and do a port scan, I don't see anything listening on that port. Any troubleshooting tips?

Comment: i'm not sure, sorry. i use actual k8s clusters in azure in my work. never used `minikube`.

Comment: @LeiYang: Fyi, I edited the question with output from kubectl and nc.

Comment: @DigitalEye As per time out behavior, how exactly did you set up minikube and what is the version of it? What does `minikube logs` command show to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access your application with the help of this [shortcut](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#getting-the-nodeport-using-the-service-command) - it is used to fetch minikube IP and a service’s  `NodePort`:

```
minikube service --url helloworld
```

The output of the command will display Kubernetes service URL in CLI, instead of trying to launch it in your default browser with `minikube service helloworld` command. Using this URL, you will be able to access the exposed service in the browser.

In general, you can check the list of all available services in your minikube cluster and their URLs by using `minikube service list` [command](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/service/#minikube-service-list).

Comment: what's root cause of OP's timeout do you think? how do you think your extra option `--url` will solve the timeout?